# Is the Guide the ultimate crafting guru?

Tags: terraria

In the Guide's crafting help menu, you can give him an item and he will show you what you can make with that item and which crafting station you have to use to make it.

Does the Guide know *all* of the crafting recipes? Are there any 'hidden' recipes that you have to discover for yourself by collecting all the correct ingredients and approaching the correct crafting station?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The guide *does* know all of the recipes in the game, you only need to give him a component and he will show you items that it can make. [source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide)

Answer (score 10):

Any material that can be used to make something, the Guide will know how to make.

You will also notice that every item that can be used to make something has the type "Material" in its description, so you know right away if something can be used to make something else.  Anything without "Material" in the description is not an item you can craft with.

Silt and Slush are not materials, but can be used with the extractor to 'make' random ores and gemstones.

EDIT: [Silt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Silt) can be used to craft Stucco blocks in four different colors.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the guide DOES says where to craft things.

Comment: This is good information, but there are two incorrect bits here. First, dirt and other blocks you can place _are_ materials, though primarily used to make bricks and walls. Also, the Guide _does_ tell you where to craft things. When you use the Guide's crafting menu, it tells you 'Requires a Cooking Pot' under the ingredients. This is actually how I discovered that a Cooking Pot was a crafting station.

Comment: @ken.ganong Thank you, I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @BillyMailman noted and fixed.

Comment: @Arperum - just checked on the PC version and the guide doesn't say anything about 'where' to craft - or I'm not spotting it.

Comment: @earthling42 I just went back to check, he does say it. If you place an item in the crafting slot and select a recipe it'll tell you the "required object" under the recipe, this is the crafting station that has to be nearby

Comment: My beef (yes, still, years later) is that the Guide tells you that you need a cooking pot, but there's not IN-GAME way to find out (without guessing) how to *make* a cooking pot.  Or any other crafting station.